# Better way of aligning things - especially properties for responsive

Tags: html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                $( "#suggestions" ).autocomplete({
                  source: function( request, response ) {

                             $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/solr/suggest/query/rows/10/suggestion_key/" + request.term + "/suggester/AnalyzeSuggester", 
                                function (data) {
                                    response(data);
                             });
                          },
                  open: function() { 
                       $('#suggestions').autocomplete("widget").css({
                            //"width": 400
                        });
                  }, 
                  minLength: 3,
                  autoFocus: true,
                  delay:100

                })
                $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {        
                    var t = String(item.value).replace(
                            new RegExp(this.term, "gi"),
                            "<strong>$&</strong>");
                    
                    return $("<li></li>")
                        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                        .append("<div>" + t + "</div>")
                        .appendTo(ul);
                };

                $( ".selector" ).on( "autocompletefocus", function( event, ui ) {

                } );
            });
```

```css
<style>
            html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%;  }

            #suggestions{
              width:50%;
            }

            #suggestions:hover {
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #ccc3c3;
                border-style: outset;
                border: 2px #000;
            }

            .ui-menu{
                font-size:15px;
                font-family: Arial;
            }

            .ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
                background: #6693bc !important;
                font-weight: bold !important;
                color: #ffffff !important;
            } 

            #logoDiv {
                margin-right: 10px;
                float: left;
            }

            #logoDiv > svg, #logoDiv > img {
                width: 75px;
            }

            #searchContainer {
                margin: 20% auto auto 20%;
            }

            #searchDiv {
                overflow: hidden;
            }

        </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


<div id="searchContainer">
            <div id="logoDiv">
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
            </div>
            <div id="searchDiv">
                <label for="suggestions"></label>
                <input list="suggestionInput" id="suggestions" name="ice-cream-choice" placeholder="Search customer..." />
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have the above one. I just added a reference image there but I have another image.

1. I am trying to make the page responsive - **Is it correct?**
2. I am trying to center the contents horizontally and vertically - used some % things - **is it correct?**
3. Trying to align input and image at the same starting level - I mean height - not the case now - **how can I do it in a better way?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you  share the final output that you seek. I am here to help. Have copy pasted your code for debugging. But what is your requirement. I will do it for sure :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather I expect input and image to resize when page size changes and both to be aligned at same level. Entire content to be centered horizontally and vertically

Comment: @CBroe :) Check edits now - I have harder way of doing SO tool - Fiddle was better - I tried, I don't think it is a teaching question - I am not asking how to do it - I am asking the better alternate ways if exist - I did a research so I am able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Viewport Units** like **vw** and **vh** instead of **px** and **%** for all your elements because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.

If you need more assistance let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%;  }

#suggestions{
     width:50%;
}

#suggestions:hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #ccc3c3;
      border-style: outset;
      border: 2px #000;
}

.ui-menu{
      font-size:15px;
      font-family: Arial;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
   background: #6693bc !important;
   font-weight: bold !important;
   color: #ffffff !important;
}

#logoDiv {
     margin-right:  0.732vw;
     float: left;
}

#logoDiv > svg, #logoDiv > img {
      margin-top: -0.4vw;
      width: 5.49vw;
}

#searchContainer {
      margin-top: 50vh;
      margin-left: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>\
</head>
<body><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


<div id="searchContainer">
            <div id="logoDiv">
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
            </div>
            <div id="searchDiv">
                <label for="suggestions"></label>
                <input list="suggestionInput" id="suggestions" name="ice-cream-choice" placeholder="Search customer..." />
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you check my edited question - I had hard time editing at SO tool -

Comment: @Gibbs Check my edited answer I have solved your issue like making webpage/website responsive and aligning the content in center of the page. If you need more assistance, let me know in the comments.  I will love to help you.

Comment: @Gibbs Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Comment: @Gibbs I am so happy to hear that my solution worked for you and thanks for accepting and upvoting my answer, it means a lot to me. I hope I get more chances to assist you.